# Resume a program if variable's value changes

Tags: c++, c, events, signals, semaphore

Is there a way in `c`/`c++` to pause a program (might be with `SIGSTOP`), and then to continue (`SIGCONT` ?) it when another thread changes a value of some variable?

For example:

```
int main(void) {

    int a = 0;
    createThread(&a); //creates a thread which will change a's value

    pauseMyself(); //pauses main process till a's value is changed

    /* main process gets here only when a's value has been changed */

    fprintf(stderr, "a's value has been changed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to see if it is possible so I won't need to sample `a`'s value each interval - Like a `while()` loop which checks `a`'s value each 200ms (sleeps for 200ms)

One possible solution for this problem is using semaphores:

I should initialize semaphores value to `0` (!),
Then in the `main()`, instead of `pauseMyself()` I'll do `sem_wait()`, means that the main process will stop there.

In the thread function I'll do `sem_post()` after it changes `a`'s value, so the main process will continue.

Is there another, nicer way?

Thanks.

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038786/c-timer-pausing-execution-of-program-until-finished

Comment: look at c++11's std::condition_variable... You will need to synchronize (protect with a lock) the write access to "a" to use it.

Comment: Great thanks! Is there also a nice way to do it in `C` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is [pthread condition variable](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_cond_init.html), a synchronization device:

> A condition (short for ‘‘condition variable’’) is a synchronization device that allows threads to suspend execution and relinquish the processors until some predicate on shared data is satisfied. The basic operations on conditions are: signal the condition (when the predicate becomes true), and wait for the condition, suspending the thread execution until another thread signals the condition.