# C Multithread: Wait Until (expression);

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, wait

I'm building a multithread applications.
My threads have to execute an instruction block only if a pointer becomes `!=nil`

```
void *fun(struct coordinates *app){

struct coordinates coord;
coord.x = app->x;
coord.y = app->y;
//printf("\n %p %d %d", t_queue[coord.x][coord.y], coord.x, coord.y);

while(1){
    if(t_queue[coord.x][coord.y]){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&Thread_Mutex);

            /*
                critical zone
            */


        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Thread_Mutex);
    }
    //sleep(1);
}

pthread_exit(nil);
}
```

Instead of the `if (t_queue[coord.x][coord.y])`, I'd like to use another function that really waits and does not use so much cpu (else my cpu go to 100%, only using sleep it will go down to 10% only checking if the variable become `!=` to `nil`)

Comment: It seems that you need [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables).

Comment: yes, but i can't find nothing that explain me how use it.
i tried with this code
    pthread_cond_wait(&Condition_Mutex, t_queue[coord.x][coord.y]);
but i recived segmentation fault

Comment: A condition goes along with a mutex, protecting it. Btw: Learning to code by just "*trying*" is harder then the hard way.

Comment: this is what i haven't understand..
could you explain it to me?

Comment: See the link posted by *iharob* and just scroll down a bit to find a nice example. Also it might make sense to read the rest aorund this example.

Comment: i had not realized that it is a link. i will read it now

Comment: while(1){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&Thread_Mutex);
  if(t_queue[coord.x][coord.y]){
   pthread_cond_wait(&Condition_Mutex, &Thread_Mutex);
    /*
     critical zone
    */
 
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&Thread_Mutex);
  //sleep(1);
 }
it's still wrong.. i'm not understanding the problem

Comment: The waiting pattern looks like this (pseudo-code): `lock(mutex); while (your test fails) wait(cond, mutex); unlock(mutex)` and the signaling pattern like this: `lock(mutex); set value to be tested; signal(cond); unlock(mutex)`. Read the tutorial carefully. You will find these patterns in there. Mainly this is all about protecting shared variables against concurrent/simultaneously access.

Comment: @alk: The question linked as duplicate is not really the same question at all.  [*Resume a program if variable's value changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090545/resume-a-program-if-variables-value-changes/22091026#22091026) is much closer.